# Fetch data from DB on same page

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am trying to let the user input an account number and below the business name will show.

Here is the code I am using which is called from the form:

```
 <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-xxx","xxx");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"cl49-xx");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID = '".$q."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    echo "Business Name:<table>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['businesstype'] . "</td>";

      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

When I run this code it just shows `business name:`.

Comment: i think you need mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array OR please check table

Comment: Take a look at the Procedural style example in the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php (Example #2). Your current syntax seems a bit off.

Comment: Just to be sure, the URL does look like `page.php?q=1` where this code is run, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have issue near while loop. Instead of "while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) ". Why do not you use this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$i= 0;
    while( $i<count($row)) 
          {

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['businesstype'] . "</td>";

          echo "</tr>";
           $i++;
          }
        echo "</table>";
```